# How could many connect to the same server in dialup internet?

Tags: internet

If dialup works over POTS just like a phone call, how was it possible for many people to dial the same number/connect to the same place at once? How didn't they get a busy tone?

Comment: Its the same way a company has a single main phone number that thousands of people can call and use simultaneously.

Comment: @Ron but in that case each call goes to a separate phone, whereas in the dialup case, they all go the same route, do they?

Comment: It's simply POTS call routing. In the case of a person-to-person call, all the calls end up on different telephones, but a modem-to-modem call, all the calls end up on different modems. A POTS call is a POTS call, and POTS routing has been basically the same for over 100 years.

Comment: @Ron what about the server side? How can it establish connections to many users?

Comment: That is the same way that millions of people not on a dial-up can connect to Google at the same time. That is a really broad question, and we cannot simply answer that here. Suffice it to say that everyone has a different source address, and a server can tell the difference in connections.

Comment: Ohhh ok, I forgot that there's the ISP in the middle. Well ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially because the dial up server has more than one POTS circuit associated with it.  By contrast, a residential line has one circuit, so when A calls B who is on the phone, the circuit is already tied up.  The dial up server would not have one phone line (circuit) but many, aggregated into an entity known as a trunk.  Different size trunks are possible depending on anticipated traffic patterns.  Of course, if you get it wrong, it's still possible for a trunk to fill up, and give you the busy signal.